# Hibernate date, timestamp type confusing

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, date, timestamp

I'm new to hibernate please help me. thank you.

I am confused of.. types of `hibernate`, `java`, and `oracle`.

1. I have 2 data types in *Oracle 11g Database*. -> `Date`, `Timestamp(6)`
2. I *mapped* this using *hibernate*. -> `date`, `timestamp`
3. It can be *mapped* like `Date(DB)` to `timestamp(hbm)` and `Date(DB)` to `Date(hbm)`?
4. and vice versa `timestamp(DB)` to `date(hbm)` and `timestamp(DB` to `timestamp(hbm)`?
5. then what type should I use in Java Code?

Oracle DB / Hibernate / Java Code

1. Date / date / Date or timestamp??
2. Date / timestamp / Date or timestamp??
3. Timestamp / date / Date or timestamp??
4. Timestamp / timestamp / Date or timestamp??

four cases are all possible? I am so confused.. I tested in my oracle db.

some problems occur like I can not save hours, minutes, seconds..

Help me learn the basics of hibernate.

**hbm.xml mapping file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:oracle</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">scott</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">scott</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
        <!-- <property name="hibernate.default_schema">MKYONG</property> -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <mapping resource="com/mkyong/user/DBUser.hbm.xml"></mapping>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**User Code (java)**

```
public class DBUser implements java.io.Serializable {
    private int userId;
    private String username;
    private String createdBy;
    private Date createdDate;
    private Date createdTimestamp;
    private String createdTest;
    //something getter setter ~~
}
```

Comment: Have a look at Oracle's [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14188/datamap.htm) which shows a table of exact mappings of Oracle to Java types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use for both HBM and JAVA.

**java.sql.Timestamp** for Timestamp. TIMESTAMP in Oracle
**java.sql.Date** for Date. DATE in Oracle

Both the above classes extends from java.util.Date. You can use **java.sql.Timestamp** for both but the time component will be discarded by Oracle for DATE during INSERT/UPDATE. Using **java.sql.Date** for DATE will give you clarity.

From Java 8 onwards,you can use below.

```
org.hibernate.type.LocalDateType - Maps a java.time.LocalDate to a Oracle DATE    
org.hibernate.type.LocalDateTimeType - Maps a java.time.LocalDateTime to a Oracle TIMESTAMP
```

Comment: Actually, all of those terrible date-time classes were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes. JDBC 4.2 and later provides for direct exchange of *java.time* objects.  Hibernate has been updated as well: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/HHH-8844. No need to ever touch the `java.sql.Timestamp`, `Java.sql.Date`, or `java.util.Date` classes again.

Comment: Thanks @BasilBourque I kept the answer close to the question. Now I have  update it for Java 8.